# Getting Shiny (RMarkdown) to use full browser window

Tags: r, shiny

Using RStudio 0.98.1028 on R 3.1.1 on Windows 7 64 bit, creating an interactive document using Shiny's fluidPage, sidebarLayout and sidebarPanel.  They all play nicely and as described on small-ish window sizes, but when I go full-screen with either RStudio's built-in browser or with a web-browser (IE 11), there is a massive (about 40%) area of just white-space on the left of my window that isn't being used.  What can I do to make Shiny use ALL of my browser window width?

Test case:

````
---
title: "TestBed"
author: "Derek Slone-Zhen"
date: "Tuesday, September 02, 2014"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

            actionButton("goButton", label="Submit")
      ),
    mainPanel(
        renderDataTable({
          input$goButton
          mx <- 1:10000
          dim(mx) <- c(100,100)
          mx <- as.data.frame(mx)
          mx
        } 
      )
    )
  )
))
```
````

What I don't like the look of:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to run the dev version of rmarkdown so

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```

see https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/135

Change your yaml header to:

```
---
title: "TestBed"
author: "Derek Slone-Zhen"
date: "Tuesday, September 02, 2014"
runtime: shiny
output:
  html_document:
    css: my.css
---
```

Then you can add a CSS `my.css` in the same directory as your `.Rmd` file. 
By default the markdown is placed in a bootstrap **fluid** container having `class = main-container` with default styling `margin-left: auto;`. You can change this for example

my.css:

```
.main-container{
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  }
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: These days, I also find myself adding  `margin-right: 8px !important;` and 
 `max-width: 98% !important;` to get the full windows used.

Comment: How to maximize the height? @dsz